# SharePoint calculated column using AND

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, modern-experience, calculated-column-formula

I'm wanting to create a column that will provide a yes or no answer depending on some other conditions.

I thought I found something that was going to work but it didn't.

So basically Annual pack days diff needs to be greater than todays date and Public Liability expired needs to be equal to No as well as Employers Liability expired. All the conditions need to be met for it to return Yes. If one is wrong then No needs to be returned.

```
=IF(OR([Annual pack days diff]> Today(), AND ([Public Liability expired?] = "No", ([Employers Liability expired?] ="No")), "Yes", "No"))
```

Comment: What is the data type of your `[Annual pack days diff]`, `[Public Liability expired?]` and `[Employers Liability expired?]` columns?

Answer (score 0):

If

- `[Annual pack days diff]` is of "Date" type
- `[Public Liability expired?]` & `[Employers Liability expired?]` are of "Yes/No" type

then use this formula:

```
=IF(AND([Annual pack days diff] > Today(), NOT([Public Liability expired?]), NOT([Employers Liability expired?]), "Yes", "No"))
```

If

- `[Annual pack days diff]` is of "Date" type
- `[Public Liability expired?]` & `[Employers Liability expired?]` are of "Choice" or "Single line of text" type then use this formula:

```
=IF(AND([Annual pack days diff] > Today(), [Public Liability expired?] = "No", [Employers Liability expired?] = "No", "Yes", "No"))
```

**Documentation**: [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14))

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Return your calculated field as **Single line of text**.